# implementing owin without using dbcontext class

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, owin

So I have implemented simple owin for a mvc 4 project. Now im able to save and retrive user information using the appdbcontext class correctly. My problem is for all other db operations i have wcf service layer which handles all db calls to save and retrieve data. So no db connections are opened in the web layer. but for owin i am forced to put the connection string in the web layer and make the db call in the web layer itself. is there any way to make the db contxet class send the data to my wcf service instead?My start up class is this

```
public class Startup
{
    public static Func<UserManager<AppUser>> UserManagerFactory { get; private set; }
    public static Func<RoleManager<IdentityRole>> rolemanagerfactory { get; private set; }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Account/Login")
            });

        UserManagerFactory = () =>
        {
            var usermanager = new UserManager<AppUser>(new UserStore<AppUser>(new AppDbContext()));
            usermanager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<AppUser>(usermanager)
           {
              AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
           };
            return usermanager;
        };


        rolemanagerfactory = () =>
        {
            var rolemanager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new AppDbContext()));
            return rolemanager;
        };
    }
}
```

AppUser class which i give to user  manager is this

```
 public class AppUser :IdentityUser
 {
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string addressline1 { get; set; }
    public string addressline2 { get; set; }
    public string addressline3 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public int citycode { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public int statecode { get; set; }
    public string pincode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int countrycode { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string baseGPSLong { get; set; }
    public string baseGPSLat { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

And ofcourse appdbcontext class is this

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppDbContext()
        : base("CSPL.Epons.Data.Properties.Settings.eponsmasterConnectionString")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't an issue in you taking the user verification to WCF, instead of opening a direct connection from the Web Layer, just expose and extra API and let it do the Job.

Comment: how to expose thats my question. not use dbcontext class at all would mean not using methods such as Signin and sign out.